# sending mail through the contact us form to the email specified in the contact form

Tags: php, html, email

please help me out with this problem.I have a contact form like this:

```
<div class="contact form">
       <form action="" method="get" class="formofcontact"/>
                <p>To:
                     <label>
                     <select name="select" size="1" id="select">
                     <option>Select</option>
                     <?php 
              $mvo=new membersVO();
              $mdao=new membersDAO();
              $list=$mdao->fetchAll('onlypublished');
              foreach($list as $members){?>
                <option value="<?php echo "$members->email1" . "," . "$members->email2" . "," . "$members->email3";?>"><?php echo $members->name;?></option>
                <?php
                }   
                            ?>
                     </select>
                     </label></p>
                     <p>From:
                     <label>
                     <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />                                                                                                   </label>
                     </p>
                     <p>Subject:
                        <label>
                           <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3" />
                        </label>
                     </p>
                     <p>Message:</p>
                     <p>
                       <label>
                        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">  </textarea>            </label>
                     </p>
                     <p>
                       <label>
                          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" />
                       </label>
                     </p>                                       
                    </form>
```

Now if someone wants to send email to australian representative then they select australia and they write thir email in the from textbox.Now what i am confused is to send the email in the respective email addresses selected by the viewers.

Please guys help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few points

1- Use `method="POST"` instead of GET in your `<form>` for sending large data like an email.

2- Do not put actual email addresses inside `<option>`'s value that will reveal those emails to SPAM email crawlers, just put member's id or the name itself in there:

```
foreach($list as $member) {
    echo '<option value="'.$member->id.'">'.$member->name.'</option>';
}
```

then when you receive the data find that member and get its email:

```
$selectedMember = null;
foreach($list as $member) {
    if( $member->id == $_POST['select'] ) {
         $selectedMember = $member;
    }
}
if( $selectedMember === null ) die( 'invalid member' );
```

and to send the email:

```
if(!@mail($selectedMember->email1, $subject, $body,
          "Return-Path: <$replyEmail>\nFrom: $name <$replyEmail>") )
{
    echo 'error';
} else {
    echo 'message sent successfully';
}
```

Comment: but i have to sent that email directly to the respective email address  but not through me

Comment: @nyaro it will be sent directly to `$selectedMember->email1` or whatever email you want.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP's mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Just be sure to validate the input. Make sure that your form can't be used to send spam.

Comment: +1 for the comment about the spam problem.  Based on a quick glean at the code, I think you will need to elaborate, though.  @Nyaro: **You must not create a web form which allows spammers to send unlimited amounts of messages to arbitrary recipients!**  Abandon your project until you properly understand this.